# Double integrals by first converting to Polar Form

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am learning double integrals right now and working on a problem that is asking to evaluate an iterate integral by first converting to polar coordinates.

∫∫ xy dydx  y bounds are from 0 to √(6x-x^2) and x bounds are from 0 to 6.

I know that the lower function is y = 0 and the upper function is √(6x-x^2) which is the upper half of a circle with radius 3.

I converted these y values to polar form getting new inside limits of integration from r = 0 to r = 6cos(θ).

My problem is when it comes to converting the x limits of integration to θ values.

Is it correct for me to set x = 0 and x = 6 to, 0 = rcos(θ) and 6 = rcos(θ) and then substituting in r = 6 cos(θ), getting 0 = 6cos^2(θ) and 6 = 6cos^2(θ) respectively?

Solving for θ I would get values of 0,π, π/2, 3π/2.

I understand why the new outside limits of integration are from θ = 0 to θ = π/2 by graphing on Desmos. But how can I know this without looking at the graph?

I would really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: The region over which you integrate should be $y^2+(x-3)^2\le \color{red}{9},\quad 0\le x\le 6,\quad y\ge 0\,.$ What is the radius ? What range of polar angles describe this upper half of a disk?

Answer (score 1):

The radius isn't a constant, it varies from $0$ to $3$.

$y=r\sin \theta$

$dy=r\cos \theta d\theta+\sin \theta dr$

$x=r+r\cos\theta$

$dx=-r\sin\theta d\theta +(1+\cos \theta)dr$

Are you familiar witht he Jacobian?

$(1+\cos\theta),-r\sin\theta$

$\sin \theta, r\cos\theta$

$r(\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta)+r\sin^2\theta=r(1+\cos\theta)$

Jacobian=$r(1+\cos\theta)$.

$\int_0^\pi\int_0^3r(1+\cos\theta)r\sin\theta\cdot r(1+\cos\theta)\cdot drd\theta=\int_0^\pi\int_0^3 r^3\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta)^2drd\theta$

$=\frac{81}{4}\int_1^{-1}(1+ u^2+2u)(-1)du=u^3/3+u^2+u|_{-1}^1=(7/3)-(-1/3)=8/3(\frac{81}{4})=54$